# Using flask-script together with template-filter

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application which uses jinja2 template filters. An example of template filter is as follows:

```
@app.template_filter('int_date')
def format_datetime(date):
    if date:
        return utc_time.localize(date).astimezone(london_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    else:
        return date
```

This works fine if we have an app instantiated before a decorator is defined, however if we are using an app factory combined with flask-script manager, then we don't have an instantiated app. For [example](https://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
def create_my_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if config:
        app.config.from_pyfile(config)

    return app

manager = Manager(create_my_app)
manager.add_option("-c", "--config", dest="config", required=False)
@manager.command
def mycommand(app):
    app.do_something()
```

Manager accepts either an instantiated app or an app factory, so at first glance it appears that we can do this:

```
app = create_my_app()

@app.template_filter('int_date')
....

manager = Manager(app)
```

The problem with this solution is that the manager then ignores the option, since the app has already been configured during instantiation. So how is someone supposed to use template filters together with the flask-script extension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is where blueprints come into play. I would define a blueprint `core` and put all my custom template filters in say `core/filters.py`.

To register filters to an application in flask when using blueprints you need to use [`app_template_filter`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_template_filter) instead of [`template_filter`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.template_filter). This way you can still use the decorator pattern to register filters and use the application factory approach.

A typical directory layout for an application using blueprint might look something like:

```
├── app
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py    # blog blueprint instance
│   │   └── routes.py      # core filters can be used here
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py    # core blueprint instance
│   │   ├── filters.py     # define filters here
│   │   └── routes.py      # any core views are defined here
│   └── __init__.py        # create_app is defined here & blueprint registered
└── manage.py              # application is configured and created here
```

For a minimal working example of this approach see: https://github.com/iiSeymour/app_factory

Comment: Bingo! I tried using template filters with a core blueprint, but that didn't work. The key was is to use the app_template_filter as you suggest.

Comment: Great. I'm not sure what issue you ran into so I've pushed a minimal example to github https://github.com/iiSeymour/app_factory

Comment: The issue was the template_filter does not exist in the blueprint namespace. The solution is as simple as using the app_template_filter instead of the template_filter, as you suggested and illustrate in your code example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/), which states they are two ways one can define a jinja template filter. Thus, instead of defining a decorator outside the factory, one can modify the jinja_env instead. This can be done in the app factory, for example:

```
def format_datetime(date):
    if date:
        return utc_time.localize(date).astimezone(london_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    else:
        return date

def create_app(production=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ....

    # Register Jinja2 filters
    app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime

manager = Manager(create_app)
...
```